# Arrange numbers 1 - 15 so that any sum of two adjacent numbers is a squared number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

E.g. ...13,3,1,....

I could not think of a systematic way to approach this question.  Have been pondering/making wild guesses on this for days.

Comment: See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1m7goLCJDY) for a complete discussion of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the info!

Comment: A start would be to notice that $9+7$ is the only square you can make by adding something to $9$ so you have to start/end at $9$ and continue with a $7$, so 9,7...

Comment: Or just pick some number. How about 15? You have to go to 1 or 10, so if there is a solution, it could have ... 1 15 10 ... .  Now what about 10? You have to go to 6 ... what's next?